# How to delete an Elastic IP Address in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address

I can't seem to delete it in AWS, It was not showing any options like delete or disassociate.

AWS is charging me every month for Elastic IP address usage. I'm not even using them.

Please help me, how to remove the EIP address.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

> An Elastic IP address is a reserved public IP address that you can
>   assign to any EC2 instance in a particular region, until you choose to
>   release it. To allocate an Elastic IP address to your account in a
>   particular region

AWS Charges you for every EIP you have which is not used (=not associated to any resource)

To release (=delete) an Elastic IP, follow these steps:

1. Go to the EC2 console
2. Under the Network & Security tab, choose
   Elastic IPs
3. Select the IP address you wish to remove
4. Click on actions and choose `Release Address`.

If the option `Release Address` is greyed out, it means that the IP address you've selected is still associated with a resource. Then you'll need to click on `Disassociate Address` first.

Comment: Thank you, I always looking for the delete option.

Comment: How do you know whether EIP is in use? I was just looking at my bill and tracked an EIP without any EC2 instances in the same region...

Comment: If you login to AWS and go to EC2 and click on Elastic Ip's on the left side, you will  have a nice overview of all your elastic IPs. Every IP that is listed there, that does not have a private IP, is unused.

Comment: It says "Disassociate address" for me, and trying it, it says "You do not have permission to access the specified resource.", so it won't let me. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your IAM access rights. Something is missing there

Comment: @Jonny The IP may be associated with a NAT gateway.

Answer (score 32):

For those getting the following error when trying to disassociate an Elastic IP address.

> "You do not have permission to access the specified resource."

I found that I still had the IP associated with a NAT Gateway. So you would need to delete the NAT, disassociate the IP, then you can release it.

Comment: For those wondering how to delete the NAT Gateway:
 1. go to VPC
 2. check the region
 3. select the NAT Gateways on the left
 4. delete the one associated with your EIP

Answer (score 3):

if `Associate address`, `Release address`, and `Disassociate address` all are greyed out for you, and you see association id in the details pane, it probably is still assigned to VPC/NAT Gateway or some service. delete that service first, then you'll be able to release the IP.

It was assigned to NAT gateway in my case, which I deleted but still it was not letting me release the IP. I had to delete VPC.

Comment: Just deleting NAT gateway solved for me, thanks for sharing.